# A confusing "participial phrase"----

Tags: participle-clauses, participle-phrases

I found a sentence in Collins online dictionary under the entry of **boarded-up:**

> Mary went to one of the boarded-up windows, **peered through the crack.**

As there is a **comma** so it should qualify **Mary.**

But this format is really new to me.

There would be no difficulties if it were:

> ...**, peering through the crack.** (*with a comma)*

Or,

> ....**cracked everywhere.** *(Without a comma)*

Please explain the sentence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's sounds bit weird. "Mary went to one of the boarded-up windows, **and** peered through the crack." is better, or: "Mary went to one of the boarded-up windows, peered through the crack, **then** instantly regretted doing so." Without a conjunction it sounds a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if the dictionary has trimmed a sentence, leaving something that is rather odd.  It would be fine to have:

> ..., and peered through a crack.

Or

> ... , peer through a crack, and saw ....

I'd gues that the original sentence was like the latter. The editor has trimmed down the last part (for reasons of space) but not inserted "and".

I don't think its a participle phrase. I think it is past tense.